# RDP error while trying to establish connection

Tags: rdp

I get this message while trying to connect to a remote host through RDP
(I'd like to point out the fact that until yesterday things went smoothly)

```
This computer can't connect to the remote computer.
Try connecting again. If the problem continues, 
contact the owner of the remote computer
or your network administrator
```

Further details:

- host is reachable through LogMeIn
- ping is enabled
- Terminal Service is set to automatic (started)
- Windows firewall disabled
- netstat -a -o command shows that another application is using port 3389

Can that be something related to the hardware firewall (Fortinet).. I don't think so, since 
the host can connect to the internet

Any clue? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `netstat -ano` to show the PID. Then `tasklist.exe /fi "PID eq ###"` to see what it is.

Comment: So you're saying I should kill the process holding port 3389? But I get PID 942 which is "svchost.exe" ...if I kill it, Windows starts shutting down

Comment: Run `tasklist /svc` and see what's in that svchost.

Comment: `netstat -a -o command shows that another application is using port 3389` - The server is listening for incoming connections to port 3389. There's always an RDP listener waiting for new connections. This is not your problem.

Comment: After that should I use taskkill?

Comment: @joeqwerty You said.."This is not your problem"..So I was wrong in saying that another application is listening port 3389..right?

Comment: Yes. You were wrong in that assessment. The server is listening for incoming connections to port 3389. There's always an available RDP listener waiting for incoming connections. This isn't the cause of your problem.

Comment: Right..my assessment was wrong ..how would you go about it?

Comment: Try connecting from another system in the same local area network. That will either confirm or eliminate a network firewall issue.

Comment: in your netstat output did the connection show up as 0.0.0.0:3389?

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to write it as a comment but it was too long...

There's one troubleshooting step you can take which I believe will help you identify the source of your issue.

Use another computer on your network (in the same LAN) to connect the remote problematic computer using telnet, like so: 
`telnet remote_computer_ip 3389`

If the response looks like that:

```
Trying 10.13.0.2...
Connected to 10.13.0.2.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Then it means that the remote computer listens on port 3389 (RDP's default port) and it also means that there's no network / firewall issue and that a connection can be established between these two computers on port 3389.

If your remote host doesn't respond to telnet then I'd try the following things:

- Check that you are trying to connect to the right IP, if it's a dynamic connection and the router disconnects and then redials it could be that your route will get a new IP lease from the ISP's DHCP server.
- Double check (even if it worked yesterday and you didn't change anything since then) that remote desktop is enabled:
  Right click My Computer and choose Properties, click Advanced System Settings, select the Remote tab and it's in the lower bottom of the screen, also, just for the test, make sure that the second option is selected, which says that any version of RDP client can connect to the host.
- Check in the Windows Firewall settings that firewall is disabled for all profiles: Domain, Private, Public.
- Hold `Windows key + R` and type: `eventvwr`, under Windows Logs, choose Application and use the filter in the right panel to display only errors, then look for errors regarding RDP.

There's one more thing I'd check, and that's the router, it usually comes with a built-in firewall which you can configure to allow traffic to the local network through specific ports, it's called NAT and if that would be the case I will help you configure the correct rule.

By the way, in regard to your question, the fact that the computer has access to the internet doesn't mean it has access from the internet toward your private network which is what you need.
Most if not all firewalls, by default block all incoming traffic and allow all outgoing traffic.
When configuring a new firewall for example, you start from the basic rule which is "Deny All" and then you continue adding "Allow" rules.

Please let me know if any of these steps help you find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to '**RDP-Tcp Properties**' Administrative Tools\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration

In Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration.
Set Security Layer to 'RDP Security Layer'

Make sure that box unchecked  'Allow connectors only from computers using Rem. Desk. with Network Level Authentication'.